# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect. What could be the cause and how to avoid it?

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, socketexception

I'm running into a `java.net.SocketException` (Permission denied: connect) when sending a lot of requests to a server. I've tried the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` option as mentioned in other threads.
This issue only occurs after a lot of connections have already been made. The following code can be used to reproduce the issue:

```
public class Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    if(args.length == 1) {
      System.out.println(args[0]);
      for(int i = 0; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        requestURL(args[0]);
      }
    }
  }
  public static void requestURL(String targetUrl) {
    URL url = new URL(targetUrl);
    HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
    httpCon.setDoInput(true);
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpCon.getInputStream()));
    //handle response here
    rd.close();
    httpCon.disconnect();
  }
}
```

The code will successfully send the requests until the Exception occurs. This has been verified in the server's log files.

Please run the sample code only against a server that you are permitted to, as it generates quite a bit of traffic / load on the server.

So the question now is: How to avoid that Exception? Or any workarounds? And what is the actually issue here?

**EDIT**

added `httpCon.disconnect()`. (doesn't solve the problem)

**EDIT #2 (StackTrace)**

```
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at Example.requestUrl(Example.java)
    at Example.main(Example.java)
```

When the issue occurs no further requests are sent to the server (no log entries on the server and no SYN packets (sniffed with tcpdump)).

**EDIT #3**

I've forgotten to run the application with the `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` argument.
It hasn't thrown an exception yet when using both, the aforementioned argument and the `httpCon.disconnect()` method.

Comment: You should post a stack-trace.

Comment: What is the exact exception? Is it from your code or the server you connect to (rate limiting for instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use httpCon.disconnect() to be sure to realease the socket after you finish to read the response.